# Whether I use 1 port for 1000 connections, or 1000 ports w/1 connection each?

Tags: tcp, port, limit, connection

I'm receiving lots of information per client, and i don't know how to handle it. If i make lots of connections to one port will it work? Now, I'm using 1000 ports open with only one client. Do I change?

Comment: If you make lots of connections to one port it will work.

Comment: Please provide more details about your client, server and problem with data handing.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, one application or one major part of application should have its own port. For each client that connects to the port, you spawn a process/create a thread to service it. After the service is complete and the reply sent back, if connection is not persistent, you close it.
After all, you can only have 65535 ports open on your pc (theoretically), and not all of those are available for private (non system) applications either.
So the way to go is to have one port for application/major application functionality. E.g.
Database Management Systems (e.g. DB2) can have a (theoretical) max limit of 64000 connections per port. 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pim/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wpc.adm.doc%2Fdata_admin%2Fwpc_con_managedb2connections.html

Comment: I would say that a TCP server can have max 2^16 simultaneous connections from the same IP. E.g. a client machine can have 2 IPs and can establish 2^17 simultaneous connections to the same server's TCP port. The limit of server's connection to the same listening port defines by the number of unique pairs of clients IP:port and TCP stack configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple clients can connect to the same listening port, so you only need to open 1 port in most cases (some protocols, like ftp, use multiple ports).  It is the combination of client IP/port and server IP/port that uniquely identifies a connection, so it works just fine.  There are multiple programming models available to allow a server to service multiple clients at one time.